# Filtro utilizando máscaras no n2-smart-table

Tags: angular

Estou utilizando Angular 6 com **[n2-smart-table](https://akveo.github.io/ng2-smart-table/#/)**. Eu quero pesquisar uma string com e sem máscara (como um cpf ou cnpj).

Ex.: `28871154000178` e `28.871.154/0001-78` devem retornar o mesmo registro **ao pesquisar pelo filtro**.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Pesquisei em várias fontes, mas não encontrei uma solução.

Grato desde já!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Existe um item na documentação que pode ser elaborado uma função customizada para filtro](https://akveo.github.io/ng2-smart-table/#/documentation), na pergunta diz que o valor tem que ser obrigatoriamente pesquisado sem os pontos, traço e barra, então dentro do `settings` no item `columns` configure dentro do campo referente ao `cnpj` o `filterFunction` igual abaixo:

```
settings = {
    columns: {
      id: {
        title: 'ID'
      },
      name: {
        title: 'Full Name'
      },
      cnpj: {
        title: 'Cnpj',
        filterFunction(cell: any, search?: string): boolean {
          const searchNumber = search.replace(/\D/g, '');
          const cellNumber = cell.replace(/\D/g, '');
          return cellNumber.includes(searchNumber);
        }
      },
      email: {
        title: 'Email'
      }
    }
};
```

Na função:

```
filterFunction(cell: any, search?: string): boolean {
  const searchNumber = search.replace(/\D/g, '');
  const cellNumber = cell.replace(/\D/g, '');
  return cellNumber.includes(searchNumber);
}
```

os valores são passados a duas outras variaveis sem os pontos, traço e a barra facilitando ai a pesquisa e com a função `includes` é verificado o se os valores são contidos, independente se são digitados com a formatação ou sem.

***Referencias:***

- [Documentation](https://akveo.github.io/ng2-smart-table/#/documentation)
- [filterFunction example request](https://github.com/akveo/ng2-smart-table/issues/354)
- [Filter using range n2-smart-table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44632139/filter-using-range-n2-smart-table)